# Demonstrating a class that prints the combination of a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, oop

I am dealing with a 'homework' problem however the professor isn't explaining anything so I can't offer a lot more.
Direct quote of the question:

> "Create a class that prints the combination of strings. The program should use two constructors, the first constructor should be an empty constructor that will allow the declaration of an array of string. The second constructor will initializes the length of the string , allocate the necessary space for the string to be stored and creates the string itself using strcpy.Your program should consist of one member function that concatenates two strings. It should estimate the length of the string to be joined, allocate the memory for the combined string and then uses strcpy() to copy the string and strcat() to concatenate the strings."

I'm having trouble understanding what I actually need to do here. Will appreciate some help Thanks.
EDIT: I'm having trouble with understanding how to use two constructors when my object will be a string array as well. Do I allocate on the heap? is there an alternative to strcpy? VS recommends using strcpy_s instead (which hasnt worked in my case so I used a #define statement to ignore deprecated warnings)

Comment: which part is unclear? The assignment is quite instructive and tells you what to do.

Comment: btw if your prof lets you struggle with homework without introducing you to the necessary basics, then thats a problem we cannot solve on SO, you need to have a chat with the prof

Comment: The prof is not helpful at ALL this semester but I need to get the work in one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you could not understand all the requirements.

I am not your teacher, so I can only tell you what I understand from your post.

> the first constructor should be an empty constructor that will allow the declaration of an array of string

It is common to create an empty (also said *default*) constructor, because it is required as soon as you will want to create arrays of objects of that class. Initialization can be defered up to the call of another method, or set the object in a default state.
Let us go on

> The second constructor will initializes the length of the string , allocate the necessary space for the string to be stored and creates the string itself using strcpy

Ok, this is the normal constructor that will build an initialized (immediately useable) object. As a remark, your teacher requires you to use C strings and C function, and raw allocation. You will later learn that modern C++ avoids  that.

This duality in constructors is common in C++. For example, in `ifstream` has a default constructor requiring later initialization with the `open` method, and a (full) constructor taking a filename as parameter and immediately opening it. Or the class `std::string` as a default ctor that creates an empty string, and another one that takes a `char` array and initializes the string from it.

Still one step further:

> Your program should consist of one member function that concatenates two strings.

Ok, it is now more clear. You are required to implement the following

```
class Xxx {
public:
    // default ctor, initialize an empty string
    Xxx();
    // normal ctor, initialize the string
    Xxx(const char *src);
    
    // the main method what will add characters to our string to get our_src + src
    y concat(const char *src);
};
```

Remarks:

- you should use a better name than `Xxx` - no doubt that you can find one :-)
- I made `concat` return `y`. The most common usages are to return nothing (`void`), the object itself or a const reference to it. It depends on how the method is expected to be used. Without knowing more, the simpler way is probably to return `void`

---

Per your last questions, I assume that your teacher expects you to use either `malloc` and `free` or `new[]` and `delete[]` to allocate the character arrays. This is called dynamic allocation. Using a heap is only a possible implementation of it.

`strcpy` is a function of the standard C library which is included in the standard C++ library. It is required to be available in any environment (even if MSVC requires special compilation options). `strcopy_s` is only an extension from Microsoft. It has been added to the standard but only as an optional function. It may not be available if you use a different compiler. So unless you teacher says differently my advice is to stick to `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

As far from my understanding, you have a class that we can call StringBuilder

This is just a basic sketch for your help.

StringBuilder has two constructors

```
StringBuilder(char* mystring) // will store myString in an internal buffer

StringBuilder(char* myString, int mystring_len) // will read the length of mystring
// perform allocation and copy the string to new created buffer
```

and a method

```
string_join(char* string1, char* string2)
```

that will allocate a buffer of length string1+string2, and apply strcat

I suppose that string_join works with previously defined strings from the constructor

I hope this can clarify you a bit, but if I were in your shoes I would ask your teacher

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  yes I did ask the teacher first but he didn't respond .-.